# Affect CultureInfo for all application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to set CultureInfo in all application to ensure that the decimal separator is not changed. (MVC Application)

Answer (score 0):

To set the culture for your application, you set the globalization element in the web.config. eg

```
<system.web>    
<globalization culture="en-AU"/>
....
</system.web>
```